# common mule data weave function that can be called from multiple data weave scripts

Tags: mule, mule-component, dataweave

In flow 1, i have a data weave script like this

```
%output application/java
%function fun1(str)
    xxxx   //do some steps         
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
element1 : fun1(payload01.element1)
}
```

In flow 2, i have a data weave script like this

```
%output application/java
%function fun1(str)
    xxxx  //do some steps            
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
entity1 : fun1(payload01.entity1)
}
```

fun1 is repeated in data weave in flow 2.. How can i make fun1 a common data weave function so that i can call from data weave in both flow 1 and flow 2?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can create an external `.dwl` file under `src/main/resource` folder and put your dataweave script there. This `.dwl` you can share with both the dataweave component. for example:

In flow1:-

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message in flow1">
     <dw:set-payload resource="classpath:test.dwl"/
</dw:transform-message>
```

In flow2 use the same `.dwl` file :-

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message in flow2">
       <dw:set-payload resource="classpath:test.dwl"/>
</dw:transform-message>
```

Pls note you can share the script if you are using entire script in dataweave.  But if you want to use any particular function of a dataweave component, better go for **global function** which can be used in any of your dataweave.

ref:- https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/48759/how-to-use-java-functions-in-dataweave.html
https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/50391/using-java-class-in-global-functions.html

Comment: I do not want to use the entire script in dataweave in both the flows..I am interested in  only the function..Also i do not want to use global function because the data weave function has data weave specific code like as :localdatetime etc; I guess in that case there is no way other than repeating the data weave function in both the flows ?